# Имитировать клик в нужное место ContentEditable

Tags: javascript, javascript-events, mouse-event, редактор, contenteditable

- Пишу текстовый редактор, нужно чтобы при клике за пределами
  Contenteditable элемента курсор становился в ближайшую возможную
  позицию в Contenteditable, в общем, чтобы как в ворде при клике вне
  страницы курсор становился на край строки.
- Предполагаемое решение - имитировать нажатие кнопки мыши в нужной мне
  позиции, будто пользователь сам поставил курсор в то место.
- Проблема-не работает.
- Делал проверку, событие на элементе срабатывает, однако желаемого
  эффекта постановки каретки в место клика нет.

x,y - координаты нужного мне места над Contenteditable

```
 document.elementFromPoint(x, y).dispatchEvent(new    MouseEvent('mousedown', {
                           'bubbles': true,
                           clientX: 1,
                           clientY: 1,}))
```

Comment: Не очень понятно что вам нужно. Например, есть слово `Паровоз` и если я кликну ниже элемента с contenteditable, но под буквой `р`, то "открывается" режим редактирования и курсор должен стоять после этой буквы `р`?

Comment: да, именно такой эффект при клике ниже и должен быть, соответственно если клик правее contenteditable, то курсор встанет после последней буквы в строке на Y уровне этого клика, при клике левее-перед первой буквой в строке на этом уровне, выше contenteditable-после самой верхней буквы, над которой произошел клик. Подобное поведение есть в том же ворде, если кликать по полям вокруг своего текста

Comment: Вопрос почти будет решен, если узнать, как [поставить курсор на конкретное положение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091730/get-and-set-cursor-position-with-contenteditable-div/34214130) Далее, contenteditable внутри состоит из одних div. Можно вначале создать - вставить один div с текстом и измерить его высоту (getComputedStyle().height), удалить. При клике вне блока, по координатам клика можно тупо циклом посчитать, который по счету блок попадает рядом. getBoundingClientRect(), offsetTop, scrollTop могут пригодится.

Comment: Если кликнули ниже/выше, циклом пройти по тексту крайнего блока и каждый символ добавлять в запасной скрытый блок, измерять его ширину. Как только дошло до координаты e.pageX, это и будет числом, куда нужно тыкнуть каретку)